# How to stop a loop when a specific token is read without skipping to the next token?

Tags: java, file, while-loop, java.util.scanner

The file I am reading has a `String` followed by an `int` on one line and then continues on until it reaches this character: `*`

For example:

```
A 1300
B 1200
C 1100
D 1000
*
```

I need it to stop reading the file, and stop looping once it reaches the star. When I did an if statement, it did not read in `*`, it would skip to the next line, as expected, but that causes alignment issues with the next token that is read in.

Here is my code:

```
static GradingScale reportCard = new GradingScale();
public static void main(String[] args) {
    readInputFile();
    javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,reportCard.toString());
}

public static void readInputFile(){
    try{
        Scanner file = new Scanner(new File("grades.txt"));
        int maxPoints = file.nextInt();
        reportCard.setMaxPoints(maxPoints);
        while(!file.hasNext("*")){
                String grade = file.next();
                int points = file.nextInt();
                double percent = points/(maxPoints*1.0);
                reportCard.addGradeLevel(grade, points, percent); 
        }
    }
    catch(java.io.FileNotFoundException fnfe){
        javax.swing.JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "File not found");
    }

}
```

I tried using the `hasNext(Pattern)` method but I keep getting this error:

```
at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1955)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.sequence(Pattern.java:2123)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.expr(Pattern.java:1996)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1696)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:1351)
at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:1028)
at java.util.Scanner$1.create(Scanner.java:367)
at java.util.Scanner$1.create(Scanner.java:365)
at sun.misc.LRUCache.forName(LRUCache.java:72)
at java.util.Scanner.hasNext(Scanner.java:1400)
at mp1.MP1.readInputFile(MP1.java:32)
at mp1.MP1.main(MP1.java:23)
```

Which leads to this:

```
private void dispatchUncaughtException(Throwable e) {
    getUncaughtExceptionHandler().uncaughtException(this, e);
}
```

Am I doing something wrong with the method or should I be doing something else entirely?

I'm very new to java, so please try to be as easy to understand as possible.
I apologize if this is hard to read; this is my first post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The parameter to `hasNext()` is a regular expression, and `*` is an invalid regex because a star means "zero or more times" the preceding expression, and there is no preceding expression.

You have to escape the star: `hasNext("\\*")`

Alternative: `hasNext(Pattern.quote("*"))`

See the javadoc of [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for more information about regular expressions.

Answer (score 5):

[`Scanner#hasNext(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNext(java.lang.String)) accepts a **regex pattern**.

But you seem to need to search for literal `*`.

So escape it with,

```
Scanner.hasNext("\\*");
```

or

```
Scanner.hasNext(Pattern.quote("*"));
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

Better use BufferedReader to read the lines. Here's a tutorial about it. http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-file-from-java-bufferedreader-example/

And have a condition to break the loop when you reach "*".